# Video JS not applying to new video elements

Tags: html, flash, video, video.js

I'm building a site which has a tabbed popup, with one tab showing videos, which shows info relating to an item you select.

However, when you close that pop up and open another, the video shows as the standard HTML 5 player- with no video js skin or flash player.

I load this whenever the popup is loaded (just in case- i never used to):

```
_V_("playa", {controls: true, autoplay: false, preload: "auto", techOrder: ["flash","html5"]}, function(){ });
```

I have this when you select a new video in the pop up:

```
_V_("playa").ready(function(){
           var myPlayer = this;
            myPlayer.src(url);
            myPlayer.currentTime(0);
            myPlayer.play();
        });
```

And this when I change tab in the pop up:

```
        _V_("playa").ready(function(){
          var myPlayer = this;
          myPlayer.pause();
        });
```

This is the only times I really reference the player, yet I'm plagued with errors.

I get this with the flash player if I change the tab or close without pausing:

```
> ["Video.js: currentTime unavailable on Flash playback technology
> element.", TypeError]  video.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Object
> #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'vjs_getProperty'
```

If I use the HTML 5 player of Video JS and try to change the video I get:

```
[DOMException, "Video is not ready. (Video.js)"]
```

Please someone help, I've spent ages looking around and nothing seems to work! I will love you forever.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the players variable:

Video JS 3.x

```
_V_.players = {};
```

Video JS 4:

```
videojs.players = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/189#issuecomment-18777663):

> You you should run `myPlayer.dispose()`